# What is a good pattern for storing implementations of an interface and retrieving specific implementations?

Tags: java, interface, subclass, simulation

I am writing a simulator that has several interfaces which all simulated objects implement. The `Entity` interface has methods that all objects must have, such as ID retrieval and advancing the time step for the object's state. `Collidable` extends `Entity`, and represents anything with volume and position that should be considered when collision detection algorithms run. `Field` extends `Entity`, and represents anything that maps a location to a value; these are used to model things like magnetic fields that permeate the world but have no volume or physical form. `RigidBody` is a class that implements `Collidable` and provides rigid-body dynamics algorithms. I have a `World` class which manages all `Entities` and has methods for advancing the simulator's clock and partitioning the world so as to make collision detection more efficient.

My issue involves retrieving `Entity` subtypes from `World`. Originally, `World` just had a map of `Entities` keyed by ID, and to retieve a `Field` or `RigidBody` there would be methods that would grab the `Entity` out of the map and do an `instanceof` check plus a cast to the desired subtype. I'm well-aware that `instanceof` usage is frowned upon, however, so I tried another approach.

Currently, I have separate maps within `World` for each interface. For instance, there is a map for `Collidables` as well as a map for all `Entities`. The `addCollidable()` method will add to both maps, and `getCollidable()` will retrieve only from the `Collidable` map. This avoids `instanceof`, but it still seems like poor design to me. If I dream up another interface to extend `Entity`, I'll need another map in `World` and corresponding methods.

I feel like this issue isn't terribly obscure, so what is typically done in this situation?

**EDIT**

I don't believe the Visitor pattern will work here, as Visitor allows you to dispatch on the concrete type, and some of my retrieval methods need to retrieve interface types. For instance, Visitor would work if `World` only needed methods to retrieve `RigidBodies` and other such concrete classes, but I cannot make a method that retrieves all `Collidables` with Visitor.

Comment: You can have something like `<T extends Entity> T getEntityFromMap(Clase<T> clazz)`, this method removes the need of `Collidables` map, and you just ask for `getEntityFromMap(Entity.class)` to get an Entity in its most general case, and ....

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can use is visitor pattern, This tutorial on Visitor Pattern use it against a similar issue you are having.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSEyIXnknoY

Comment: This is close to what I need, but unfortunately Visitor dispatches on concrete types, and I require the ability to dispatch on abstract/interface types as well as concrete types.

Answer (score 1):

Using `instanceof` is frowned upon because it *often* appears in contexts where it hints at incomplete encapsulation. For example, `instanceof` is sometimes used to distinguish between different kinds of objects and then operates on them depending on their type. A cleaner way of doing this could be to put the code into the corresponding classes of the objects and to use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) instead. So, instead of *never* using `instanceof`, rather ask yourself whether your current use of `instanceof` might be **legitimate**?

In other words:
**Is it possible to move the code that depends on the type of the entity into the corresponding entity class?**
(*Of course, once you reach a conclusion this should be documented, as things may change.*)

BTW I think you can easily **generalize you current design** by using a `Map<Class,List<Entity>>`, which would allow you to keep entity lists for an arbitrary number of types. You could also have an array `Class[] types = {...}` that contains all types that need to be distinguished. 
Now you only need a single `instanceof` operator in a `for` loop within your `add/removeEntity(...)` methods, which would walk through all the types that need to be distinguished and adds/removes the entity to/from all relevant lists.

Answer (score 0):

It seem plausible to me, that you use an extra field for the collidables in your world class, as it is a special subset of data, that requires specialized handling.

The only thing i would change (mostly due to personal taste) though, is using `List<Collidable>` as type, because for your needs - iterating through all of them for collision checks - a list is a faster & more lightweight approach.

Comment: The question I would have here is that when some object `obj` implementing `Collidable` is added to `World`, how will `World` be able to tell that `obj` should be put into the `List<Collidable>` without using an `instanceof` check?

Comment: I assume you already have something like `World.addEntity(Entity newEntity)`
Just add `World.addEntity(Collidable newCollidable)`, implement it appropriately, and let javac handle the rest.